# CUDA - Malloc inside kernel ( compute_50,sm_50 )

Tags: cuda

I had a problem while running a program with the CUDA Memory Checker.
In other threads on stackoverflow, the main problem with using malloc inside a kernel was that the "compute_50,sm_50" was not set properly. Here the code compiles so this is not the problem.

**The problem is now solved, but I don't understand why the new code solved the problem.**
My question is: why it is working now ?

Old code:

```
__device__ unsigned int draw_active_levels(curandState * localState,const int num_levels_max){
    unsigned int return_value = 0;
    float draw;
    draw = curand_uniform(localState);
    int num_active_levels = floorf(draw * (num_levels_max - 1)) + 1;


    double * arrLevelWeights = (double*) malloc((num_levels_max+1) * sizeof(double));
    arrLevelWeights[num_levels_max]=0.0; //<--------Error on this line
    double level_weights = 1.0 / num_levels_max;
    for(int i=0; i<num_levels_max; i++){
        arrLevelWeights[i] = level_weights;
    }
    //...
    //do some operations using arrLevelWeights
    //..

    free(arrLevelWeights);
    return return_value;
}
```

Error with old code:

```
Memory Checker detected 2 access violations.
error = access violation on store (global memory)
gridid = 198
blockIdx = {1,0,0}
threadIdx = {29,0,0}
address = 0x00000020
accessSize = 8
```

New code:
I just added a few lines to check if malloc returned a null pointer.

```
__device__ unsigned int draw_active_levels(curandState * localState,const int num_levels_max){
    unsigned int return_value = 0;
    float draw;
    draw = curand_uniform(localState);
    int num_active_levels = floorf(draw * (num_levels_max - 1)) + 1;


    double * arrLevelWeights;
    arrLevelWeights = (double*) malloc((num_levels_max+1) * sizeof(double));
    if(arrLevelWeights == NULL){
        printf("Error while dynamically allocating memory on device.\n"); //<--- this line is never called (I put a breakpoint on it)
    }
    arrLevelWeights[num_levels_max]=0.0; //<-------Error disapeared !
    double level_weights = 1.0 / num_levels_max;
    for(int i=0; i<num_levels_max; i++){
        arrLevelWeights[i] = level_weights;
    }
    //...
    //do some operations using arrLevelWeights
    //..

    free(arrLevelWeights);
    return return_value;
}
```

Comment: You're probably allocating too much memory. The device heap has a default size of 8 MB.

Comment: You are right, it was about memory space, I missed a free() in a completely unrelated part of the code. Do you want to put it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: Obviously there were other changes you made to your code.  If you add a line of code and it's never called, that obviously can't be the issue.  Your questions are perplexing.  I'm puzzled how *any* answer to this question could actually answer the question, specifically how adding lines of code that never get called could have "fixed" the problem.

Comment: I notice weird things like this as well with CUDA.  I had some code where it would always throw access violations, until I did a printf, then it would work and just print out "everything is okay" until completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `malloc` returns `NULL`, it simply means that you've run out of device heap space which has, by default, a size of 8 MB. I'm not sure how adding a line that is never executed fixes the problem, though.

As you said in a comment, you ran out of heap space because of a missing `free` somewhere else in your code, which is why I suggest you use RAII (with your own smart pointer class) for memory allocations to avoid this kind of problem in the future.